# Qt KeyPress Event on QlineEdit

Tags: c++, qt

i searched over the net on how to capture a key press event only on a specific QWidget ( a QlineEdit ) 
one way to do is to inherit from that class and over ride the virtual keyPress function , 
but i cant do that since i'm using QtDesigner ( is it possible to do it with QtDesigner ? )

i also tried to over ride the KeyPress Event on the entire windows but i need to filter only the the events when a specific lineEdit is active which i could not find a way to do so ( but there must be a way )

over all what is the best way to sole this problem ? thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't do this with `Designer`.If you don't want to use inheritance, then you should use event filter. For example:

```
bool Dialog::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (obj == ui->lineEdit && event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        QKeyEvent *key = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
        qDebug() << "pressed"<< key->key();
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

To use `eventFilter` you should also:

```
protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);//in Dialog header
```

and

```
qApp->installEventFilter(this);//in Dialog constructor
```

Comment: Thanks :) and what is exactly the aApp that you are referring to ? app object in main.cpp file ?

Comment: it works , but only catches events when the focus is on the main window of the app , shouldn't i do sth like ui->lineEdit.installEventFilter() ?

Comment: @user3798072 http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qapplication.html#qApp for details. It catches event from lineEdit, if filter can't catch event from lineEdit , then lineEdit has no this event now.